# Any code outside 'it' doesn't work with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I used protractor as a scraping tool (like https://github.com/motemen/example-scrape-websites/blob/master/protractor/mufg.js) but today my code has changed to be impossible to work.

I spent a long time to find the reason, and found that any code outside 'it' sentence doesn't work.

```
describe( 'Start Scraping', function () {

  // Use Protractor with the site which doesn't use AngularJS
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  /*
   * Fail because not inside of 'it' sentence
   */
  browser.get( 'http://www.google.com' );
```

Is this change inevitable? Do I have to give up Protractor-Scraping?

Biggest probrem is variable definition because the variable between multiple 'it' sentence is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why Protractor test doesn't work recently is bug of latest Chrome driver. You can run test with Firefox!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` to a `beforeEach` block, but your `browser` related code will have to go in an it block. This is due to the way that protractor queues up browser requests.

I'd personally use [nightmare](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) or phantom for web scraping. You're going to be fighting protractor a lot to use it for anything but integration tests (I fight it even when I do integration testing ^^)

Comment: Thank you Nick. After all, I've found the reason.